# Deploy Grafana dashboard from Postgres (helm chart)

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, grafana, dashboard

I have a Grafana deployment from Kubernetes with Helm which is working fine.
Now I am trying to store the panels in Postgres so I can call them from Helm.

After json exporting the panels from Grafana, I have created a table in Postgres and inserted them as follows with no problem.

```
CREATE TABLE dashboards (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  dashboard JSONB
);

INSERT INTO dashboards (name, dashboard)
VALUES (id, 'My Dashboard', '<JSON del dashboard>');
```

I have configured the link to Postgres from the Helm's values.yaml file, but I don't know how to call the dashboard stored in the database, from the Dashboard tab.
I currently import them from the code repository correctly, but it's not the solution I need.

```
dashboardProviders:
  dashboardproviders.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    providers:
    - name: 'iot1'
      orgId: 1
      folder: 'IoT'
      type: file
      disableDeletion: false
      editable: true
      options:
        path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/iot1

dashboards:
  iot1:
    sample:
      file: dashboards/iot/sample.json
```

Any idea how to call them from Postgres in the values file? Thank you.